# How to define spring profile on AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I have deployed my war file on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk as a java app.

I want to specify on AWS : spring.profiles.active like I do when I execute:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod target/gaming-boost-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I can only configure "Environment Property" on "Configuration"

Answer (score 7):

Set below environment variable in ElasticBeanStalk

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

Comment: In fact, now it has to be `spring.profiles.active`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021794/2135973

The casing is different when set as an Environment Variable versus the command line property. Try setting SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE in your EB Configuration.